# UIView Hides on Keyboard Appear

Tags: ios, swift, uikeyboard

Pop up UIView hidden when keyboard shown or click on Textfield!

My Code for KeyBoard show:

```
func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue() {
        if self.view.frame.origin.y == 0 {
             self.view.frame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height
        }
    }
}

func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue() {
        if self.view.frame.origin.y != 0 {
            self.view.frame.origin.y += keyboardSize.height
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: due to neagtve frame value y , print it , manage it accordingly

Comment: Rephrase your question please, it is very hard to understand what do you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Your code for setting UIView frame when keyboard show up is wrong.

Replace

```
self.view.frame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height
```

by

```
self.view.frame.origin.y = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height - (keyboardSize.height + self.view.frame.size.height)
```